# Unable to SSH into GCE server

Tags: google-compute-engine

I set up a default image GCE VM on GCP - works perfectly on one project (UAT), but when trying to replicate in other project (Prod); I'm unable to connect.

I can see from the serial port output that port 22 is open with sshd listening, but I cannot even telnet to the server, let alone ssh - any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Please check the firewall rules if nothing is blocking port 22, check Internal firewall (on an instance VM; are you using Linux ???), check the routes and try to ssh into this machine from another VM that's inside the same VPC. If this doesn't help please provide more detail and I will try to help you troubleshoot this issue. You can also have a look at the official documentation: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-ssh

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your response. I've checked netstat on the serial console and port 22 is open and sshd is listening but when I try to telnet externally (even from Google Cloud Console), I'm unable to reach the host. This happens on every GCE instance I create on this project, but works perfectly fine on my other project.

Comment: But did you check firewall rules ? It's really important to be sure - otherwise we might just guess what's wrong.

Comment: I did - I have the default allow ssh firewall rule setup so it should be working from what I understand...

Comment: Can you connect to the VM via SSH from outside the VPC network (using public IP) ? - I mean get user/password prompt ?

Comment: no, the connection times out when I try from Putty too... both the gcloud cli and the UI show that default-allow-ssh is enabled, the server shows port 22 is open and listening - I'm so confused...

Comment: I just found the network interface details page on Google Cloud Console and my instance has the default-allow-ssh rule listed, but then it's not in the ingress analysis below - see image here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1iVH_s9UH1rCL49kcbUIR2TGhL-KTG-WY/view?usp=sharing

Comment: "when trying to replicate in other project" - what do you mean? What exactly do you replicate: existing boot disk, VM instance configuration with static IP addresses or something else?